# python issubset compare two sets with different element order

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, set, unique, series

I have a set `values = set(['', nan, 'X'])`. I also get the unique values from a `Series`, and put these values in a set called `uniques`, which has values `{'nan', 'X'}`, I tried to use `uniques.issubset(values)` to compare the two sets. but the result is `False`. so I guess `nan` is not the same as `'nan'`?

ps. the values of the sets are read from `PyCharm` debugger.

Comment: Sorry you want to compare `NaN` with the string `'nan'` why do you expect that to work? also you should use `.isnull()` or `.pd.isnull()` to test for `NaN`

Comment: you can easily check it yourself - just execute: `'nan' == np.nan`

Comment: @MaxU  Note however that np.nan == np.nan is False too. ;-)

Comment: @JohnE, good point, i've totally forgotten about that, when i was writing my comment